# EF - Eager include grandchildren not working, does not contain definition for 'Select'

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, c#-3.0

I am working in VS 2015 solution with an MVC 5 project and a code library project using EF 6.1. I have redone the entire project from a previous version in VS 2013 hoping it would resolve this problem, but no luck. I am just trying to eager load a child with grandchildren. I tried this:

```
            Test t = db.Tests
                .Include("TestsRemoteOBD")
                .Include("TestsRemoteOBD.TestsRemoteOBDDtcs")
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

and this:

```
            Test t = db.Tests
                .Include(i=>i.TestsRemoteOBD)
                .Include(i=>i.TestsRemoteOBD.Select(s=>s.TestsRemoteOBDDtcs))
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Include using the string works for the child, but not the grandchildren. And with the 2nd query, I'm getting this error:

'`TestsRemoteOBD`' does not contain a definition for '`Select`' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type '`TestsRemoteOBD`' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've seen the same question resolved by adding "`using System.Data.Entity;`", but I had done that a long time ago. No help. What else could I be missing?

Thanks!

Comment: What error is the first snippet giving you?

Comment: Is `TestsRemoteOBD` a collection?

Comment: From error message looks like `TestRemoteOBD` is a single entity reference, so simply remove the `Select`.

Comment: I would avoid the first method which relies on magic strings. Try projection so see what you get: var test = db.Tests.Select(t => new { parent = t, child = t.TestsRemoteOBD, grandchild = t.TestsRemoteOBD.TestsRemoteOBDDtcs }).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: first snippet gives no errors and TestsRemoteOBD record is accessible after datacontext is disposed, but trying to acces the grandchild table TestsRemoteOBDDtcs, said to me "an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code". I'm certain I'm using it wrong and will try these suggestions, but why is VS gi

Comment: sorry, didn't mean to post that yet... in new VS 2015 version, I let EF build the classes code first using existing database, really easy, parent table is Test, child is TestsRemoteOBD, its children are TestsRemoteOBDDtcs. The only squiggly line I get in the second statement is under "Select".

Comment: And TestRemoteOBD is not a collection, it is 1-to-1 with Tests

Comment: I did want to avoid the include with strings, doesn't seem to work as expected anyway. I will try playing around with the suggestion now, just got back from lunch.

Comment: Of, I think I get it, no collection means it would have no select? Will test.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much, to all those who commented. I would have been banging my head for another day, at least. The way I had written the second statement would have worked fine if the parent [Tests] had a 1-to-many relationship with [TestRemoteOBD], but since the latter was not a collection, there was no 'Select' defined. I have not tested, but I believe it should be something like:

```
Test t = db.Tests
            .Include(i=>i.TestsRemoteOBD)
            .Include(i=>i.TestsRemoteOBD.TestsRemoteOBDDtcs)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I still cannot seem eager load TestsRemoteOBDDtcs, still getting the exception if I look at it after datacontext is disposed. I find that if I just check t.TestsRemoteOBDDtcs.Count() while the datacontext is open, then I can read it just fine after closed. That is my short-term fix, and I'm going to move on and try not to think about it, but will keep checking back to see if anyone has an idea. Thanks again, all! It's nice to understand why I was seeing 'Select not defined'.

Answer (score 1):

Bump. Found this and thought I'd throw in my own research.

Microsoft's 

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.include(v=vs.113).aspx)
 
states: To include a reference and then a reference one level down: query.Include(e => e.Level1Reference.Level2Reference)
 -- but this doesn't seem to work under even the simplest use case. Executing the query with a .ToList() does not actually include anything. Smells like an obvious bug to me!

I can see 2 workarounds.
First, as Ben here suggests, you can manually iterate over the entities to force EF to load them.
Second, if scoping permits, you can forget the 'using' block and keep a more permanent instance of the dbcontext as a class member so that it's still available, not disposed (System.ObjectDisposedException), when the members are accessed.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I never did fix it.

Comment: This problem came up the other day for me working in EF Core, in a different project, and in the newer framework you can solve the original problem like this... Test t = db.Tests
                .Include(i=>i.TestsRemoteOBD)
                .ThenInclude(t=>t.TestsRemoteOBDDtcs)
                .FirstOrDefault();